# Uploading a video using Laravel9, inertia, Vue3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I tried to make a course table, courseImages table, CourseVideo table,
I succeded to upload images but i didn't for the videos
here is my model Course.php about the video :

```
public function video(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CourseVideo::class);
    }
```

and here is my model courseVideo.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class CourseVideo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['filename'];
    protected $appends = ['src'];

    public function course(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }
    public function getSrcAttribute()
    {
        return asset("storage/{$this->filename}");
    }
}
```

here is my video controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\CourseVideo;

class RealtorCourseVideoController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Course $course)
    {
        $course->load(['video']);
        return inertia(
            'Realtor/CourseVideo/Create',
            ['course' => $course]
        );
    }

    public function store(Course $course, Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
            $request->validate([
                'video.*' => 'mimes:mp4,ogx,oga,ogv,ogg,webm'
            ], [
                'video.*.mimes' => 'The file should be in one of the formats: mp4'
            ]);
            foreach ($request->file('video') as $file) {
                $path = $file->store('video', 'public');

                $course->images()->save(new CourseVideo([
                    'filename' => $path
                ]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my video migration :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('course_videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('filename');

            $table->foreignIdFor(
                \App\Models\Course::class
            )->constrained('courses');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('course_videos');
    }
};
```

here is my Create.vue:

```
<template>

  <div>
    <div>Upload New Videos</div>
    <form @submit.prevent="upload">
      <section class="flex items-center gap-2 my-4">
        <input
          class="border rounded-md file:px-4 file:py-2 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 file:text-gray-700 file:dark:text-gray-400 file:border-0 file:bg-gray-100 file:dark:bg-gray-800 file:font-medium file:hover:bg-gray-200 file:dark:hover:bg-gray-700 file:hover:cursor-pointer file:mr-4"
          type="file" multiple @input="addFiles"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn-outline disabled:opacity-25 disabled:cursor-not-allowed"
        >
          Upload
        </button>
        <button
          type="reset" class="btn-outline"
          @click="reset"
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>




<script setup>
import { useForm, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
const props = defineProps({ course: Object })
Inertia.on('progress', (event) => {
  if (event.detail.progress.percentage) {
    NProgress.set((event.detail.progress.percentage / 100) * 0.9)
  }
})
const form = useForm({
  video: null,
})
const upload = () => {
  form.post(
    route('realtor.course.video.store', { course: props.course.id }),
  )
}
const reset = () => form.reset('video')

</script>
```

and here is my web.php aboute the video routes:

```
Route::prefix('realtor')
    ->name('realtor.')
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::resource('course', RealtorCourseController::class)
            ->only(['index', 'destroy', 'edit', 'update', 'create', 'store', 'show']);
        Route::resource('course.image', RealtorCourseImageController::class)
            ->only(['create', 'store', 'destroy']);
        Route::resource('course.video', RealtorCourseVideoController::class)
            ->only(['create', 'store', 'destroy']);
    });
```

I'm expecting to recieve the video in my database, but nothing arrive!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

$request cannot receive from react as uploadedFile i.e hasFile

This is sent as base64 image/video so get it using has function only

get and save it like this.

add uploadImage function in model class

```
public function uploadImage($request,$fileNameColumn,$deleteOldFile = false)
{
    

    if ($request->has($fileNameColumn)  && (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $request->{$fileNameColumn}, $type) || preg_match('/^data:video\/(\w+);base64,/', $request->{$fileNameColumn}, $type))) {
        $dir = '/uploads/videos_'.$this->id.'/'.$fileNameColumn;
        $fileName = Str::kebab ($this->id.uniqid('vid_').time());
        
        $details  = UploadsService::uploadBase64($request->{$fileNameColumn},$dir,$fileName,true,true);
        $this->{$fileNameColumn} = $details['url'];
        $this->save();
    }
}

public static function uploadBase64($image_64,$directory,$filename,$replace_file_name_if_matched = false,$delete_if_name_is_matched = false)
{
    $decodedImage = self::base64ToImage($image_64);
    $file = self::decodedImageToUploadedFile($decodedImage);
    $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ';')))[1])[1];
    $filename = $filename.'.'.$extension;
   
    $data =  self::uploadAccordingToStorageDisk($file,$directory,$filename,$replace_file_name_if_matched,$delete_if_name_is_matched);
    unset($file);
    return $data;
}

public static function base64ToImage($image_64)
{
    $replace = substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ',')+1);
    $image = str_replace($replace, '', $image_64);
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $decodedImage = base64_decode($image);
    return $decodedImage;
}

    public static function decodedImageToUploadedFile($decodedImage)
{
    //save in temp dir
    $tmpFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . Str::uuid()->toString();
    file_put_contents($tmpFilePath, $decodedImage);
    // this just to help us get file info.
    $tmpFile = new File($tmpFilePath);
    $file = new UploadedFile(
        $tmpFile->getPathname(),
        $tmpFile->getFilename(),
        $tmpFile->getMimeType(),
        0,
        true // Mark it as test, since the file isn't from real HTTP POST.
    );
    unset($tmpFile);
    return $file;
}


    public static function uploadAccordingToStorageDisk($file,$directory,$filename,$replace_file_name_if_matched = false,$delete_if_name_is_matched = false)
{
    
    $filename = str_replace(['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '<', '>', '\\', '/', '//', ' '], '', $filename);

    checkIfDirectoryIsAvailable($directory);
    if($delete_if_name_is_matched){

        checkIfFileIsUploadedThenDelete(asset($directory.'/'.$filename));
    }
    if($replace_file_name_if_matched){
        $isUploadedWithSameName = checkIfUploadedFileHasSameName(asset($directory .'/'. $filename));

        $filename = $isUploadedWithSameName ? time() . '_' . $filename : $filename;
    }
    $filename = time() .'_'.$filename;

    $uploaded = $file->move(
        public_path($directory) //directory from public path becomes location of the file in uploads
        ,$filename);
    if($uploaded){
        return ['url' => $directory .'/'. $filename, 'name' => $filename];
    }
    throw new \Exception('File could not be uploaded');

}
```

call imageUpload file after creating record.

```
$course->uploadImage($request,'video',true);
```

Comment: I think you gived me the ImageUpload but it's already working for me, I;m asking for the VideoUpload if you can help me, Thanks a lot

Comment: its for both type files